# SQL catch 22 in nested queries ? (what is the order of execution ?)

Tags: mysql, relational-division

Suppose we have a table vv and a table r
We run the following query to simulate a set division.

I understand this query runs like a nested for-loop 
The question is this: In the deepest nested query how can we use table vv1 while it's construction is not yet complete ?

I thought the 'select' clause is the last one to be computed, so how does mysql know that vv1 has distinct values (or which values it has at all) before completing the where clause, but to complete the where clause it must completed it first ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT vv1.y
FROM   vv AS vv1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT r.A
                   FROM   r
                   WHERE  r.A NOT IN (SELECT vv2.x
                                      FROM   vv AS vv2
                                      WHERE  vv2.y = vv1.y)); 


+------+ Table r
| A    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+

+------+------+ Table vv
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
|    1 | A    |
|    2 | A    |
|    3 | A    |
|    1 | B    |
|    2 | B    |
|    3 | C    |
|    3 | D    |
+------+------+
```

Try it here: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81f9e/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [*correlated subquery*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) For each row in the main `vv1` table, it runs the subquery with all the `vv.colName` values replaced with the corresponding entries from the main table. So it doesn't try to compute the inner query all at once, it does it repeatedly for each row of `vv1`.

See also [this tutorial](http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/understanding-correlated-subquery/) on correlated subqueries, it includes an example where the subquery is in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Are all subqueries in the WHERE clause repeated for each row, or only correlated subqueries?

Comment: It only does it for correlated subqueries, which are queries that refer to tables in the outer query.

Comment: ... but to iterate vv1, it must know what rows it has ... and how does it know the contents of vv1 before computing them ?

Comment: In any query, the `WHERE` clause is executed by iterating all the rows in the table, testing them against the conditions there.

Comment: ok, so it takes vv1 as a whole and applies "DISTINCT" to it straight at the get go ? ... and *then* it tests each of it's rows one by one to either keep or throw out ?

Comment: You're all turned around. `vv1` is the whole table. It tests each row against the `WHERE` clause (which includes running the subquery) to get the result set. Then it removes duplicates if you have the `DISTINCT` option.

Comment: GOT IT ! ... this thing sent me for a mind spin for sure. Thanks for your help.